# How to add hooks for Play Evolutions?(play-framework)

Tags: playframework

I want to do some cleanup/backup activities before the evolution starts.
Is there any way i can add a hook to play evolutions?

Details.
My issue is that i want to use a single build across multiple tenants with multiple schemas..So i cannot rely on the sbt task as the actual compilation and packaging happens at one server.And then based on the tenantname, i would like to pick up the evolution sqls and execute.